# c# generic function - an extension of another generic

Tags: c#, generics

Here's a typical example of a generic method in c#:

```
ParseObject po;

int i = po.Get<int>("someField");
string s = po.Get<string>("anotherField");
```

I want to write an **extension** that will work like this ...

```
 int i = po.ExampleGet<int>("someField");
 string i = po.ExampleGet<string>("anotherField");
```

So,

(a) the extension ExampleGet would have to be able to accept a < class > in the same way that ParseObject.Get does, and

(b) the extension ExampleGet would have to be able to call ParseObject.Get (as well as doing other work).

What's the syntax for such n extension, which uses a generic in that way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly you are looking for [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
static public class Extensions
{
  static T ExampleGet<T>(this ParseObject po, string name)
  {
      return po.Get<T>(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah fantastic.  I use extensions everyday (thank goodness) -- I did not understand the syntax for a generic.  Brilliant!